# Symfony 3 with JQuery UI cannot render widgets

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, twig, symfony

I want to fancy up a Symfony 3 application with some nice JQuery UI widgets. At the moment it is a Accordion. But the accordion is never rendered. For the installation of JQuery UI I followed the instructions of BMatzner [here](https://github.com/bmatzner/BmatznerJQueryUIBundle).
My base twig template now looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}*************{% endblock %}</title>
        {% block scripts %}
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerjqueryui/js/jquery.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerjqueryui/js/jquery-ui.js') }}"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerjqueryui/js/jquery.ui.accordion.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
    {% block stylesheets %}
        <link href="{{ asset('css/mainstyle.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerjqueryui/css/overcast/jquery-ui.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="{{ asset('bundles/bmatznerjqueryui/css/overcast/jquery-ui.theme.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
    {% endblock %}
</head>
<body>
    {% block body %}{% endblock %}
    {% block footer %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

The template, where the accordion has to be looks like this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}
{% block scripts %}
  {{ parent() }}
  <script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
    });
  </script>
{% endblock %}
{% block stylesheets %}
   {{ parent() }}
   <link href="{{ asset('css/sstm_style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
   <link href="{{ asset('css/bnme_style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}
{% block header %}
    <header role="banner">
        <div id="syslogo">
            <p>Benutzer: {{ user.getAnrede() }} {{ user.getVorname() }} {{ user.getNachname() }}</p>
            <button onclick="location.href='{{ path('logout') }}'";>Abmelden</button>
        </div>
        <div id="right_head">
            <div id="date_time">
                <script type="text/javascript">showTime();</script>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>
{% endblock %}
<div id="sysname"><h1>Benutzermenü</h1></div>
<nav>
    <div id="accordion">
    <p><a href="#">Modulgruppe 0</a></p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 0</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 1</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 2</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 3</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#">Modulgruppe 1</a></p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 0</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 1</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 2</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 3</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <p><a href="#">Modulgruppe 2</a></p>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 0</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 1</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 2</a>
            <li><a href="#">Modul 3</a>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </div> 
</nav>
```

I can't figure out, what went wrong there. All I see on the rendered page is, well, a list of hyperlinks where I expected the accordion with the links in it.

Comment: Could you include the script that initialises the accordion too?

Comment: I tried this but with no effect :(

Comment: Okay, but could you include it in the question? See [mcve]

Comment: Of course. I added the line in the first codesnippet in the scripts block

Comment: No, i mean the script that *initialises* the widget. It should contain something that looks like `$("#accordion").accordion({ /* options */ })`, see [the examples](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/)

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean. I added it but still the accordion isn't rendered.